# SharePoint 2013 Manage Permissions of Users from trusted Identity Provider

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, permissions, trusted-identity-provider

In SharePoint 2013, what permissions does a user need to be able to read users from a Trusted Identity Provider?  I have one configured and Site Collection admins have no trouble modifying permissions, but everyone else does.  I have a couple Full Control users that should be able to edit permissions on sites, but the people.aspx page bombs out with this exception:

```
Application error when access /_layouts/15/people.aspx, Error=User cannot be found.  
at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPList.GetItemById(String strId, Int32 id, String strRootFolder, Boolean cacheRowsetAndId, String strViewFields, Boolean bDatesInUtc, Boolean bExpandQuery)
at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPList.GetItemByIdSelectedFields(Int32 id, String[] fields)
at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages.PeoplePage.GetCurrentGroupListItem(String field)    
at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages.PeoplePage.OnLoad(EventArgs e)    
at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()    
at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)

System.ArgumentException: User cannot be found. 
at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPList.GetItemById(String strId, Int32 id, String strRootFolder, Boolean cacheRowsetAndId, String strViewFields, Boolean bDatesInUtc, Boolean bExpandQuery)
at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPList.GetItemByIdSelectedFields(Int32 id, String[] fields)    
at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages.PeoplePage.GetCurrentGroupListItem(String field) at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages.PeoplePage.OnLoad(EventArgs e)    
at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()    
at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
```

There must be a permission I am missing elsewhere I can use beside Site Collection Admin to allow my full control users to edit permissions of users from the Trusted Identity Provider.  Any ideas?

EDIT:
It is a global issue for anything related to users from the Trusted Identity Provider.  Access requests show as empty users, documents show empty usernames etc